# how to Three.js shape line series with width/thickness increase?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I am using three.js. I draw two dimensional object shape. I attempt to draw line width/thickness increase along with separate line. is possible to only separate line thinness increase?.  i tried different but doesn't work. Below my code.

```
function doubleSquareDraw( startX, startY, endX, endY, color ) {

        var geometry, points;
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: "#000000",lineWidth: 25 } );

        //

        var bedShape = new THREE.Path();
        //bedShape.lineWidth = 25;         does not work.
        bedShape.moveTo( startX, startY );
        bedShape.lineTo( endX, startY );
        bedShape.lineTo( endX, endY );
        bedShape.lineTo( startX, endY );
        bedShape.lineTo( startX, startY );

        points = bedShape.getPoints();
        geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
        var bed = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

        return group;
}
```

Here I tried to line width/thinness ingress `var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: "#000000",lineWidth: 25 } );` not working.

Comment: if your operating system is windows, then `lineWidth` property will not have any effects. [ Read about it here : ](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/LineBasicMaterial.linewidth)

Comment: yes, i am using windows 7. is possible to `lineWidth` increase? or anything solution? @HariV

Comment: Have a look at this [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fat#webgl_lines_fat).

Comment: This one also, [meshline](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine)

Comment: Thank you for your replay. offical example i have seen it. `THREE.LineMaterial` use. now current version not available  `LineMaterial.js` therefore i get the error message `THREE.LineMaterial is not a constructor` @prisoner849